# Coq match on Hypothesis passed to Ltac tactic

Tags: coq, coq-tactic, ltac

I'm new to Coq, currently on the [`IndProp` chapter](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/lf-current/toc.html) of Software Foundations.  I'm curious about learning to write my own simple tactics to automate certain kinds of reasoning, but unfortunately the [official documentation](https://coq.github.io/doc/v8.10/refman/proof-engine/ltac.html) is a bit impenetrable to me as a beginner.

I'd like to write a tactic that applies in the following scenario:

- The current goal is `False`
- There is a hypothesis of the form `P \/ False`

Based on the following lemma, we should be able to replace the current goal with `~P` in this scenario:

```ml
Lemma orfalse_lemma : forall P : Prop,
  P \/ False -> ~P -> False.
Proof.
  intros P [H|H] HP.
  - apply HP. apply H.
  - apply H.
Qed.
```

We can use the lemma manually with the desired effect:

```ml
Example ex_orfalse_1 :
  (1 <> 2) \/ False -> (False).
Proof.
  intros H. apply (orfalse_lemma (1 <> 2)). apply H.
  (* goal:  ~ (1 <> 2) *)
Admitted.
```

I want to automate this, so I wrote a simple tactic to apply the lemma when the goal and context match this scenario:

```ml
Ltac orfalse :=
  match goal with
    | [H : ?P \/ False |- False ] => apply (orfalse_lemma P) ; [> apply H | ]
    | _                           => fail "expected goal to be False"
  end.
```

It works as expected.  However, **when there are multiple hypotheses matching the pattern, we don't have the option to choose between them**:

```ml
Example ex_orfalse_1 :
  (1 <> 2) \/ False -> (False).
Proof.
  intros H. orfalse.
  (* goal:  ~ (1 <> 2) *)
Admitted.

Example ex_orfalse_2 :
  (false <> true) \/ False -> (1 <> 2) \/ False -> (False).
Proof.
  intros H1 H2. orfalse.
  (* goal:  ~ (1 <> 2) *)
  (* what if we want the goal to be ~ (false <> true) instead? *)
Admitted.
```

I assumed fixing this problem would be as simple as just passing the desired hypothesis to the `orfalse` tactic as an argument:

```ml
Ltac orfalse H :=
  match goal with
    | [|- False ] =>  match H with
                      | ?P \/ False => apply (orfalse_lemma ?P) ; [> apply H | ]
                      | _  => fail "expected disjunction with false"
                      end
    | _ => fail "expected goal to be False"
  end.
```

However, using it in a proof fails:

```ml
Example ex_orfalse_2 :
  (false <> true) \/ False -> (1 <> 2) \/ False -> (False).
Proof.
  intros H1 H2. orfalse H1.
  (* Tactic failure: expected goal to be False. *)
Admitted.
```

If I replace the first case of the nested match with just `?P` and return `idtac ?P`, it just prints the name of the hypothesis I pass in (e.g. `H1` or `H2`), so my guess is that the match happens on the identifier itself and not on the hypothesis.

So, my question is:  **If I pass the name of a hypothesis to a tactic, how do I correctly match on the structure of that hypothesis?**  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to Coq!

There are two minor issues with your tactic. First you must not match the value of `H` - which either would be a proof term or the value of `H` is simply `H` and cannot be further evaluated - you must match the type of H. Then when using match variables, no ? is required. This works:

```
Lemma orfalse_lemma : forall P : Prop,
  P \/ False -> ~P -> False.
Proof.
  intros P [H|H] HP.
  - apply HP. apply H.
  - apply H.
Qed.

Ltac orfalse H :=
  match goal with
    | [ |- False ] => match type of H with
                      | ?P \/ False => apply (orfalse_lemma P) ; [> apply H | ]
                      | _  => fail "expected disjunction with false"
                      end
    | _ => fail "expected goal to be False"
  end.

Example ex_orfalse_2 :
  (false <> true) \/ False -> (1 <> 2) \/ False -> (False).
Proof.
  intros H1 H2. orfalse H1.
Admitted.
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about `type of`!  This also helped clear up some confusion.  Before I expected the type of `H` to be `Prop`.  However, after checking the Wikipedia page for CoC, it appears `H1` is a proof, whose type is the proposition `(false <> true) \/ False`, distinct from the type of the proof `H2`.  That proposition has the type `Prop` which is shared by all propositions.

Comment: Indeed this can be confusing. There is a Coq command `Check` which allows to look at the type of arbitrary terms. Think about how `1=1` and `1=2` relate (and not relate) to `True` and `False`.